# « En » redondant ?

Tags: sens, en

Petite question :

> Indique qu'une action en suit une autre

Dans la phrase ci-dessus, est-ce que « en » est redondant ?

La phrase sans « en » sera aussi correcte et aura le même sens, n’est-ce pas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pour compléter la réponse existante, on peut dire cela suit le même schéma que dans  :

> Ma voiture ne marche plus, j'**en** veux une autre (sous-entendu : de voiture).

> Indique qu'une action **en** suit une autre (sous-entendu : d'action)

La phrase sans le "en" n'est syntaxiquement pas correcte, elle reste en suspens :

> Indique qu'une action suit une autre [une autre quoi ?].

Elle redevient valide si on la complète, mais devient redondante :

> Indique qu'une action suit une autre action

En revanche, si on la complète avec un autre nom, c'est valide mais le "autre" n'a plus vraiment de raison d'être :

> Indique qu'une action suit une autre procédure

Comment: Merci pour la précision !

Comment: Une action suit une autre, une action suit l'autre, me semblent tous 2 valides et clairs...

Answer (score 2):

Tout dépend de ce que l’on qualifie de redondant. La phrase est correcte avec ou sans le ‘en’, mais le ‘en’ peut être nécessaire pour préciser que l’on parle bien de l’action et pas d’autre chose.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse !

Answer (score 0):

Le [TLFi, **I. A. 2. a)**     EN², pron. atone de la 3e pers.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en) fournit la définition suivante et le cas d'usage en question.

> **I. A. 2. a)**
>
> **I.** [L'antécédent est explicite et de nature nom.]
> **A.** [L'antécédent est un subst., un adv. ou un pron.]
> **2.** [L'antécédent est repris avec une détermination propre qui ne figure pas dans l'antécédent; en corresp. à l'art. indéf.]
> **a)**  [Le déterminant est un quantificateur qui précise une partie par rapport au tout que l'antécédent est supposé représenter]
> − [un numéral indéf.]
> **En ... un autre** « Je ne peux pas vous aimer... j'en aime une autre... » (Meilhac, Halévy, Grande duch. Gérolstein,1867, II, 7, p. 255).

Dans le contexte d'utilisation « en » a pour antécédent, par convention un tout que le locuteur doit déterminer (dans le tout de <…> ou dans l'ensemble de(s) <…>); il faut remarquer que, à proprement parler il ne s'agit pas d'un antécédent puisqu'il y a toujours cette partie fixe (qui n'est d'ailleurs pas unique mais seulement représentative de ce qui peut être utilisé). Il  n'est pas  difficile lorsque le concept est énoncé dans le contexte, de déterminer cet antécédent . C'est le cas des deux examples qui suivent.

- 1/ Un train peut en cacher un autre. (*Le tout est tout simplement l'ensemble des trains, et la logique voudrait que l'on se limite à l'ensemble des trains qui peuvent passer sur la voie parallèle, mais ce n'est pas vraiment un problème.*)
- 2/ C'est un cèpe ! Tiens ! En voilà un autre ! (*Ensemble de tous les champignons que l'on appelle cèpes.*)

Dans certains cas le nom clé qui fournit l'antécédent (le tout de < … >) ne se trouve pas dans le contexte linguistique et doit être déduit. C'est le cas dans l'exemple suivant.

3/ Je ne peux pas vous aimer... j'en aime une autre... (*Puisque le locuteur s'adresse à quelqu'un, qui ne peut être qu'une femme, et qu'il affirme que la raison pour ne pas pouvoir l'aimer est qu'il aime quelqu'un d'autre, ce quelqu'un d'autre doit être dans l'ensemble des femmes; donc, ce qui complète l'antécédent n'apparait pas dans le texte.*)

Si l'on fait certains remplacements assez stricts, en prenant pour modèle un des examples ci-dessus, on obtient ce qui suit. (On peut tout aussi bien choisir *Une action en suit une autre.*.)

- (A) Un train peut cacher **un autre train** dans l'ensemble des trains.      (*not usual but grammatically correct*)

  ↓      même sens
- Un train peut cacher dans l'ensemble des trains **un autre train**.      (*syntaxiquement incorrect*)

↓      même sens

- Un train peut cacher **dans l'ensemble des trains** *un autre*.      (*syntaxiquement incorrect mais transformation habituelle de l'adjectif en pronom par élimination du nom*)

↓      même sens

- Un train peut *dans l'ensemble des trains* cacher un autre.      (*syntaxiquement incorrect parce qu'un complément circonstanciel qui n'est pas un pronom ne se trouve jamais à cette place*)

↓      même sens

- Un train peut en cacher un autre.      (*forme habituelle*)

En suivant cette progression on peut se convaincre qu'il n'y a pas de redondance; ce que l'on peut dire c'est qu'il existe une spécification du contexte qui est plus ou moins extrême, plus ou moins inutile; on voit cela très bien dans « (A) ». On peut s'en rendre compte  en considérant que le pronom « en » s'élimine facilement si on réintroduit le nom; on exprime exactement la même chose de cette façon.

- Un train peut **en** cacher un autre.
- Un train peut cacher un autre **train**.

La fonction syntaxique de « un autre », en tant que pronom, c'est à dire la fonction de « spécifier sur l'ensemble des trains un élément indéfini » (l'ensemble des trains étant « en » (rappel)), équivaut aux fonctions syntaxiques combinées de l'article « un » et de l'adjectif « autre » qui détermine  « train », lequel mot est aussi l'ensemble des train si considéré en isolation. On voit dans cette équivalence que la caractéristique de spécifier quelque peu excessivement est confirmée par la seconde forme, de laquelle quiconque familier avec le français dira qu'elle n'est pas du meilleur style, trop lourde; elle est pourtant strictement équivalente à la précédente.

Il faut néanmoins comprendre que ces formes sont énormément utilisées et que l'on doit les considérer comme seules correctes, seules idiomatiques: si on supprime « en » il faut absolument réintroduire le nom.